# Flutter - calculate mileage driven using geolocator and google api

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-directions-api, geolocator

I am using the Google Directions API, initially to get the detailed from/to directions, *i.e.* from let's say Denver to Chicago.

What I need to do is get *actual* road mileage as they are driving. I am successfully streaming the coordinates from the plugin by geolocator, however, when I get distance between two GPS points it's the distance, not road mileage. This should be somewhat accurate if I take enough of these little readings and add up the distance.

Is this the best way?

I could also keep calling Google API, but that gets very expensive on a long trip with lots of users.

Answer (score 0):

The API provides the distance in the route's `Leg`s. Loop through them to add up the total distance in meters.

```
DirectionsService.init('API_KEY');

final directionsService = DirectionsService();

final request = DirectionsRequest(
  origin: 'New York',
  destination: 'San Francisco',
  travelMode: TravelMode.driving,
);

directionsService.route(request, (result, status) {
  if (status != DirectionsStatus.ok) {
    // TODO Handle the error.
    return;
  }
  var totalDistance = 0.0;
  result.routes?.first.legs?.forEach((element) {
    totalDistance += element.distance?.value?.toDouble() ?? 0.0;
  });
  print("This trip is $totalDistance meters.");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is the initial call which tells me the route. It doesn't tell me where I am at on the actual route. I use the geolocator to tell me position which works fine but it doesn't tell me how many miles I have driven. I need an approach to use the actuals to tell me where I am and how many miles I have driven. Thank you for taking the time here

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that detail in your original question. In that case, the answer is no. Not because of technical reasons, but rather legal ones. https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#:~:text=(d)%C2%A0No,Android%20mobile%20app.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response. I'm not looking to recreate google map action but more of an odometer for actual mileage driven. That is probably the best way to phrase the quesiton because I'm not creating a route planning software just a %variance at the end of the trip. So the better question is how do I create an odometer for a car similar to how people are creating walks/steps in flutter. Because roads can curve and are non-linear doing a before/after geolocation isn't accurate enough unless I do it quite often

Comment: I guess if you know the user's speed via quick position updates, you can roughly guess how far they have traveled on the route. This is probably good enough for the realtime updates. Then periodically do an API query to get the true distance traveled and correct your running total if necessary.